# Determine the cyclic subgroup of $(S_5,\circ)$, the symmetric group on five symbols, generated by the cycle $(1 , 3, 5 , 2, 4)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Request vetting, as doing first time.

Let, $a= (1 , 3, 5 , 2, 4)$, then have $$a^2= (1 , 5, 4, 3, 2),$$ $$a^3= (1, 4, 2, 5, 3),$$ $$a^4= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)=e.$$ So, get order of this cyclic subgroup (as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2969007/424260)) $=4$, with elements:$\,\{e, a,a^2,a^3\}$.

*Edit*

The one line form was wrongly used to achieve squaring each time.

$$a^3= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = e,$$ $$a^4= (1, 4, 2, 5, 3).$$

Comment: You seem to be repeatedly squaring, rather than repeatedly multiplying by $a$ - I think the permutations you have computed are $a, a^2, a^4, a^8$. For example, to compute $a^3$, you should compute the composition $(1, 5, 4, 3, 2)(1, 3, 5, 2, 4)$. Also, $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ is *not* the identity permutation! This permutation sends $1$ to $2$, for example. The identity permutation has cycle type $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$, though $1$-cycles are often omitted.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thanks, have edited.

Comment: It's still **not true** that $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = e$!!! This permutation is not the identity permutation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the identity (in the original version of your question).

The cyclic subgroup contains all powers of the generator $a$, so that includes $a^0=e$.

Also,

$$\begin{align}
a^3&=(13524)a^2\\
&=(13524)(15432)\\
&=(12345)
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
a^4&=(13524)a^3\\
&=(13524)(12345)\\
&=(14253),
\end{align}$$

so that $a^4(1)=4\neq 1$, meaning $a^4\neq e$.

Comment: Will $a^4$ not the same as $e$?

Comment: So, my computation is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you were way off, @jiten. Keep going. You'll get there eventually.